# Postgresql query conditional with joins where condition is not met

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am sure the answer to this is quite simple, however a solution seems to be eluding me. Given the following example between 2 tables, named "books" and "reviews" respectively with pseudo schemas as follows:

```
books:
id 
title
author 

reviews: (adjacent review records may or may not exist)
id
book_id
rating - rating can either be "good" or "bad", stored as a varchar
```

Question:
How can I query all books, where their rating is NOT "good" - book records that do not have adjacent review records at all, or ones that are rated anything other than "good", should also be returned.

Other information:
I am running postgres 9.6.1

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help elucidate what you want to do.  What are "adjacent review records"?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   B.*
from books B
left join reviews R on (B.id = R.book_id)
where R.rating is null
or R.rating != 'good'
```

The left join will return all books that satisfy the where clause regardless of having a matching review or not.  The on clause (B.id = R.book_id) describes how the books link to the reviews when a review exists.

In the where clause, I want to keep books that either have no review (R.rating is null) or books with a not-good rating (R.rating != 'good').

Comment: Perhaps you should try to elaborate your answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your intention is this:

```
select b.*
from books b
where not exists (select 1
                  from reviews r
                  where r.book_id = b.id and r.rating = 'good'
                 );
```